# ios6 mapview can't showUserLocation when airPlane Mode

Tags: ios, mkmapview

In ios6, I choose airplane mode and open the wifi, i can't see the blue dot in mapview, but in ios5, it's well. What should i do? Please help, thanks!

```
map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
map.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;
map.showsUserLocation = YES;
[self.view addSubview:map];
```

PS: Iphone should like a iTouch with the condition, and my app can work well at the iTouch5, but bad at iphone5.

Comment: native map application is showing the blue dot on map in above mentioned scenario so it should work for you as well..wait a min..have u checked that the wifi is connected to internet..?

Comment: it need's internet to show userlocation

Comment: @Vinodh The wifi can connect to internet

Comment: Airplane mode restrict wi-fi and cellular data . It restrict both of them

Comment: @Vinodh But google'app and apple's app can work with the same condition

Comment: @samfisher, I'm sure that the wifi is well. When i close the airplane mode, it is well immediately, and when i choose airplane mode and open wifi, i can see the blue dot is disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Airplane mode turns off the cellular chip, which is on the same circuit as the GPS chip so straight way you've lost precise location services. It also turns off the wifi, but you can go into the wifi settings and manually turn it back on. Depending on which wifi hotspot you are connected to iOS may be able to work out where you are because Apple have some connection to SkyHook which has list of wifi router IDs and their locations. Since wifi is short range they can locate you to within 50ft or so of the transmitter if they have it on their list.

If you're not near a wifi transmitter, or you're not able to join a network then your device can't call back to Apple to ask for the coordinates of that wifi transmitter. Therefore it doesn't know where you are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i have understand what you mean. I'm wondering that other apps based on the LBS can show the blue dot immediately in the same conditions. How did they realize?

Comment: I had tried to CoreLocationManage and it could work well. Can it help to show blue dot?

Comment: All location services on iOS run through the same lower level stuff. If you want the blue dot then turning on the MKMapView's showUserLocation is the way to do it. iOS will do the rest. Trying to make your own blue dot through other means is a waste of time if you're just rebuilding exactly the same feature.

Comment: In my code, map.showsUserLocation = YES. At the normal mode, my app is working well, and it can show the blue dot; Set the app background, then turn on the airplane mode, manual open the wifi(wifi is well). After these action had did, make the app foreground, the blue dot was disappered. But other apps can show the blue dot all the time with the same condition. I want to know what i should do for implementing the same feature. Thanks

Comment: Try doing the background/foreground thing without turning on airplane mode, perhaps your app doesn't reconnect after being paused.

Comment: If my app doesn't reconnect after being paused, what should i do? I writed code in this method:
    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
       self.viewController.innerMap.showsUserLocation = YES;
    }
and this method:
    - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
    self.viewController.innerMap.showsUserLocation = YES
    }

Comment: And I tried on starting my app at first after turned on airplane mode and opened wifi, it also can't show blue dot. I'm Very depressed :(